# Cual es la funcion del booleano TRUE dentro de functools en este ejemplo

Tags: python

Tengo esta  pequeña duda.
Quiero comparar 2 listas y tengo este ejemplo :

```
import functools 
 
l1 = [10, 30, 45, 50] 
l2 = [10, 30, 50, 40, 70] 
l3 = [10, 30, 45, 50] 
 
if functools.reduce(lambda x, y : x and y, map(lambda p, q: p == q,l1,l2),True): 
    print ("Las listas l1 y l2 son las mismas") 
else: 
    print ("Las listas l1 y l2 no son las mismas")
```

El resultado lo da bien (si comparo l1 y l2 me dice que NO son iguales, si comparo l1 y l3 me dice que SÍ son iguales)

La duda es que hace el TRUE metido adentro del metodo functools.reduce.

Buscando en la documentación no aparece ese boleano como argumento de functools : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

Es mas , cuando pruebo el código sin ese `True` me da la respuesta buena igual.

¿Qué hace ese TRUE ahí? ¿còmo es posible que no de error, si no es un argumento de `functools.reduce`?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, según la documentación que tu aportas, la función `reduce()` tiene 3 parámetros. Esta es la función reduce en la documentación:

```
def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if initializer is None:
        value = next(it)
    else:
        value = initializer
    for element in it:
        value = function(value, element)
    return value
```

1. El primer argumento es la función, que este caso tu la creas como una función `lambda`
2. El segundo parámetro es el iterable, que es el `map()`
3. El tercero es el inicilizador, que es opcional y por defecto es `None` en este caso tu lo has definido como `True`. Lo puedes quedar como `None` ya que en el caso de tu iteración **no tiene efecto el cual sea el primer valor** con el que se inicie la función `reduce()`

Comment: El inicializador es necesario cuando una de las dos listas está vacía, con lo que `map` devuelve una lista vacía y `reduce` no se aplica.